# Ktor prompt for credentials from within route interceptor inside a basic authentication block

Tags: kotlin, basic-authentication, ktor

When I set up a basic authentication provider and put a simple `get` handler inside an `authenticate` block, I'll be prompted for credentials when I try to access the route, so once the get handler starts being executed, I can access the `UserIdPrincipal` and start finding data associated with the account. However, I now want to expand my `authenticate` block to include multiple routes, so I thought I could handle the initial processing of the principal/account inside an `intercept` block. Yet, when I try to do this, I am not prompted for my credentials and therefore the `UserIdPrincipal` inside the interceptor is null. How can I get Ktor to prompt me for my credentials from within a route interceptor inside an `authenticate` block?

This code properly prompts me for my credentials when I try to access the dashboard route.

```
authenticate("teacherAuth") {
    get("dashboard") {
        val principal = call.principal<UserIdPrincipal>()!!
        val schoolName = principal.name
        val school = transaction {
            School.find { Schools.name eq schoolName }.singleOrNull()
        }
        if (school == null)
            call.respondText("No school \"$schoolName\" found")
        else
            call.respondHtml {
                ...
            }
    }
}
```

This code does not prompt me for my credentials when I try to access the dashboard route, resulting in an error.

```
authenticate("teacherAuth") {
    val schoolKey = AttributeKey<School>("school")

    intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Setup) {
        val principal = call.principal<UserIdPrincipal>()!!
        val schoolName = principal.name
        val school = transaction {
            School.find { Schools.name eq schoolName }.singleOrNull()
        }
        if (school == null) {
            call.respondText("No school \"$schoolName\" found")
            return@intercept finish()
        }
        call.attributes.put(schoolKey, school)
    }

    get("dashboard") {
        val school = call.attributes[schoolKey]
        call.respondHtml {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be that you intercept at the wrong phase. Authentication is usually at the Features phase. You are intercepting at the Setup phase, before authentication.

Comment: Thanks, setting the interceptor phase to `ApplicationCallPipeline.Call` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the interceptor phase to `ApplicationCallPipeline.Call` fixed the issue and now prompts me for my credentials. Credit to @f-caron for the idea.